# How to get visit number for multiple different study IDs using sample dates

Tags: r, sorting, date

```
Study.ID    Visit Number    Sample.Date
2497                        24/05/2013
2497                        01/11/2017
2497                        15/07/2010
1805                        27/01/2015
1805                        14/04/2014
1805                        30/08/2017
1805                        21/09/2009
```

Lets say I have these two variables filled in my data frame. I need to input a visit number to correspond with the Sample.Date (i.e the earliest date being number 1 and the most recent being number 2,3 or 4 respectively for each Study.ID. I would really appreciate anyones input in this. The whole data frame contains over 400 different study.IDs with differing multiple visits. I really dont want to change the order of arrangement either as the samples need to be loaded into a database in the order they were scanned.

Answer (score 2):

**1) Base R** Convert `Sample.Date` to `"Date"` class and then group by `Study.ID` using `ave` and `rank` to the get the rank order.  The original order is not changed and no packages are used.

```
DF <- transform(DF, Sample.Date = as.Date(Sample.Date, "%d/%m/%Y"))
transform(DF, Visit.No = ave(as.numeric(Sample.Date), Study.ID, FUN = rank))
```

giving:

```
  Study.ID Sample.Date Visit.No
1     2497  2013-05-24        2
2     2497  2017-11-01        3
3     2497  2010-07-15        1
4     1805  2015-01-27        3
5     1805  2014-04-14        2
6     1805  2017-08-30        4
7     1805  2009-09-21        1
```

**1a) magrittr** This can be expressed using a magrittr pipeline like this:

```
library(magrittr)

DF %>%
   transform(Sample.Date = as.Date(Sample.Date, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
   transform(Visit.No = ave(as.numeric(Sample.Date), Study.ID, FUN = rank))
```

**2) dplyr**  Using dplyr the pipeline becomes:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
   mutate(Sample.Date = as.Date(Sample.Date, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
   group_by(Study.ID) %>%
   mutate(Visit.No = rank(Sample.Date)) %>%
   ungroup()
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form was assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "
Study.ID                   Sample.Date
2497                        24/05/2013
2497                        01/11/2017
2497                        15/07/2010
1805                        27/01/2015
1805                        14/04/2014
1805                        30/08/2017
1805                        21/09/2009"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `tidyverse` package and the sample data

```
library(tidyverse)
dd<-read_table("Study.ID  Sample.Date
2497      24/05/2013
2497      01/11/2017
2497      15/07/2010
1805      27/01/2015
1805      14/04/2014
1805      30/08/2017
1805      21/09/2009")
```

If you don't have any "ties" for Sample.Date, you can do

```
dd %>% 
  mutate(Sample.Date=parse_date(Sample.Date, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(Study.ID) %>%
  mutate(Visit.Number=dense_rank(Sample.Date))
```

otherwise maybe something like

```
dd %>% 
  mutate(Sample.Date=parse_date(Sample.Date, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(Study.ID) %>%
  arrange(Sample.Date) %>%
  mutate(Visit.Nuumber=row_number())
```

would help.

Answer (score 0):

After converting the dates, you can simply use the `rank()` function in combination with `desc()`.

```
df <- data.frame(Study.ID = c(2497, 2497, 2497, 1805, 1805, 1805, 1805),
                 Sample.Date = c("24/05/2013", "01/11/2017", "15/07/2010",
                                 "27/01/2015", "14/04/2014", "30/08/2017",
                                 "21/09/2009")) # data
df$Sample.Date <- as.Date(df$Sample.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y") # conversion
library(plyr)
df$Visit.Number <- rank(desc(df$Sample.Date)) # date ranking
```